# Fuzzy K-modes clustering how to find the cluster centers

Tags: artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, fuzzy

I'm trying to understand [fuzzy k-modes](http://140.115.80.66/data%20mining%20paper%20databases/IEEE%20Transactions%20on%20Fuzzy%20Systems/A%20fuzzy%20k-modes.pdf) algorithm (look mainly at page 3) in order to implement it.
I'm stuck at the **calculation of cluster centers** they said as shown in the pic
[image]
[image]

**I need to know whether the following is true or false and please correct me**

In order to get the center of a cluster we need to:

1. for each category in a variable calculate the sum of membership value for all the point, that the category belongs to, to this cluster
2. the highest obtained value to be set as the category of the center

Comment: Wl-i is the membership value of the point i to the cluster l. points will have this structure A(1000,001011,000000001) 1000 means the first variable of A has the first category on ... B(0110,100000,101010000). suppose we're working on the 1st cluster so and we knew that W1-A=0.7 and W1-B=0.6 So will we take for each category the membership of the whole point? and make the sum for each point and chose the highest??? –

Answer (score 1):

I've got to admit, interpreting that cryptic text is difficult and the first step you should take is finding some more reference material.

There's quite a lot of such material available on the web, here is one such page:
http://home.dei.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/cmeans.html

The calculation of the cluster centres is simply a weighted mean using the membership values.
[image: Prototype calculation]